Create binary matrix from dataframe of Indices for each pair of Rows
I have the following Dataframe of indexes:
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    1: [(), (1, 2), (1, 2, 5, 7), (1, 2),    (1, 2, 5), (1, 2)],
    2: [(), (1, 2), (1, 2, 5, 7), (1, 2),    (1, 2, 5), (1, 2)],
    3: [(), (3, 4), (3, 4),       (3, 5, 6), (3, 4, 6), (3, 4, 5, 7)],
    4: [(), (3, 4), (3, 4),       (),        (3, 4, 6), (3, 4, 5, 7)],
    5: [(), (),     (1, 2, 5, 7), (3, 5, 6), (1, 2, 5), ()],
    6: [(), (),     (),           (3, 5, 6), (3, 4, 6), ()],
    7: [(), (),     (1, 2, 5, 7), (),        (),        (3, 4, 5, 7)],
    8: [(), (),     (),           (),        (),        ()],
    9: [(), (),     (),           (),        (),        ()]
})

I want to obtain in an efficient way this output:
Pair_IDs, C1, C2, C3, C4, C5, C6
(1,2), 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1
(1,3), 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
(1,4), 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
(1,5), 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0
(1,6), 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
(1,7), 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0
(1,8), 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
(1,9), 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
...
(5,7), 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1 
(5,8), 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 
(5,9), 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 

In which each row is a representazion of all pairs of indexes that are in the same subset for each column.
Do you have any suggestions on how I can define an efficient Python function? Do you know is tensorflow or pandas or Spark have some methods that already process it?
Example
The pair of values (1,2) is contained in all the sets except the first one, which means:
[( ), (1, 2), (1, 2, 5, 7), (1, 2), (1, 2, 5), (1, 2)]
(1,2) => [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]

How do you get the Pair_IDs values in your output dataframe? Can you provide an example?

@xuxu I have added an example. Thanks in advance!

Thank You. That was obvious from the output - what I was interested in was the way you derived the list (1,2), (1,3), (1,4)...(5,7), (5,8) , (5,9) for the column Pair_IDs in your output.

Simply considering all the pairs of tuples: for i in range(1,10): for j in range(1,10): if j>i: print(i,j). The last pair of tuples that you see is (5,9) because it is a snippet of all results

@Stefano does the the second number j in your tuple correspond to the columns in you df?

Hope this code fits your needs. I provided a solution based on pyspark.
What I do is:

Building a combination matrix with its indices
Join the combination DatFrame to your input based on index
Work with array function from pyspark.sql.functions to identify valid intersections

It is not perfectly written but if you want feel free to beautify it a bit:
from pyspark.sql import Row
from pyspark.sql import functions as f
import pandas as pd
from pyspark.sql import DataFrame

index_range = "1-9" # (9 included)
group_range = 6 # (6 not included)

def build_range_combi_df(index_range: str) -> DataFrame:
    """
    A string written like 1-9

    """

    index_start = int(index_range.split("-")[0])
    index_end = int(index_range.split("-")[1])

    range_dict = {}
    for i in range(index_start, index_end + 1, 1):
        whole_list = []
        for j in range(index_start, index_end + 1, 1):
            my_list = [i, j]
            if i != j:
                whole_list.append(my_list)
        range_dict[i] = whole_list

    data = []
    for k, v in range_dict.items():
        row = Row(index=k, lists=v)
        data.append(row)

    df_combis = spark.createDataFrame(data).withColumn("lists", f.explode("lists"))
    return df_combis

df_combis = build_range_combi_df(index_range=index_range)

df_input = (
    pd.DataFrame({
        1: [(), (1, 2), (1, 2, 5, 7), (1, 2), (1, 2, 5), (1, 2)],
        2: [(), (1, 2), (1, 2, 5, 7), (1, 2), (1, 2, 5), (1, 2)],
        3: [(), (3, 4), (3, 4), (3, 5, 6), (3, 4, 6), (3, 4, 5, 7)],
        4: [(), (3, 4), (3, 4), (), (3, 4, 6), (3, 4, 5, 7)],
        5: [(), (), (1, 2, 5, 7), (3, 5, 6), (1, 2, 5), ()],
        6: [(), (), (), (3, 5, 6), (3, 4, 6), ()],
        7: [(), (), (1, 2, 5, 7), (), (), (3, 4, 5, 7)],
        8: [(), (), (), (), (), ()],
        9: [(), (), (), (), (), ()]
    })
    .transpose()
    .rename({i: f"C{i+1}" for i in range(group_range)}, axis=1)
    .reset_index()
)

df_input = spark.createDataFrame(df_input)
df_new = df_input.join(df_combis, on=["index"], how="left")

df_intersect = df_new.withColumn("lists_tmp", f.array_sort(f.col("lists")))
for i in range(group_range):
    df_intersect = (
        df_intersect
        .withColumn(f"intersect_{i+1}", f.array_sort(f.array_intersect(f"C{i+1}", "lists_tmp")))
        .withColumn(f"intersect_{i+1}_tmp", f.array_sort(f.array_intersect("lists_tmp", f"C{i+1}")))
        .withColumn(
            f"intersect_{i+1}",
            f.when(
                f.col("lists_tmp") != f.col(f"intersect_{i+1}"), f.lit(0)
            )
            .when(f.col(f"intersect_{i+1}") == f.col(f"intersect_{i+1}_tmp"), f.lit(1))
            .otherwise(f.lit(0))
        )
        .drop(f"intersect_{i+1}_tmp")
        .drop(f"C{i+1}")
        .withColumnRenamed(f"intersect_{i+1}", f"C{i+1}")
    )
df_result = (
    df_intersect
    .withColumn(
        "lists_to_sort",
        f.concat_ws("", "lists")
    )
    .orderBy("index", "lists_to_sort")
    .withColumnRenamed("lists", "Pair_IDs")
    .drop("index", "lists_tmp", "lists_to_sort")
)

df_result.show()

+--------+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|Pair_IDs| C1| C2| C3| C4| C5| C6|
+--------+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|  [1, 2]|  0|  1|  1|  1|  1|  1|
|  [1, 3]|  0|  0|  0|  0|  0|  0|
|  [1, 4]|  0|  0|  0|  0|  0|  0|
|  [1, 5]|  0|  0|  1|  0|  1|  0|
|  [1, 6]|  0|  0|  0|  0|  0|  0|
|  [1, 7]|  0|  0|  1|  0|  0|  0|
|  [1, 8]|  0|  0|  0|  0|  0|  0|
|  [1, 9]|  0|  0|  0|  0|  0|  0|
|  [2, 1]|  0|  1|  1|  1|  1|  1|
|  [2, 3]|  0|  0|  0|  0|  0|  0|
|  [2, 4]|  0|  0|  0|  0|  0|  0|
|  [2, 5]|  0|  0|  1|  0|  1|  0|
|  [2, 6]|  0|  0|  0|  0|  0|  0|
|  [2, 7]|  0|  0|  1|  0|  0|  0|
|  [2, 8]|  0|  0|  0|  0|  0|  0|
|  [2, 9]|  0|  0|  0|  0|  0|  0|
|  [3, 1]|  0|  0|  0|  0|  0|  0|
|  [3, 2]|  0|  0|  0|  0|  0|  0|
|  [3, 4]|  0|  1|  1|  0|  1|  1|
|  [3, 5]|  0|  0|  0|  1|  0|  1|
+--------+---+---+---+---+---+---+
only showing top 20 rows



As far as I understand you have a list of tuples (tups) you generate independent of the df's indices.
The second index j in tups seems to correspond to the columns in df as I understood from your output.
Here I don't generate tuples but a DataFrame with two columns so we can use panda's .isin() method later.
import itertools
tups = pd.DataFrame(itertools.combinations(range(10), 2))

# without itertools:
# tups = pd.DataFrame([(i, j) for i in range(10) for j in range(10) if i < j])

# Filter tuples to exclude tuples where j does not exist in df's columns
tups = tups[tups[1].isin(df.columns.unique(level = 0))]

Then we apply for each tuple the function that checks if the tuple is in the corresponding column. We use the .isin() method to check if the cells of a column in df contain the tuple.
res = tups.apply(
        lambda tup: df[tup[1]].apply(
                lambda x: tup.isin(x).all()
            ),
        axis = 1,
    ).astype(
        int
    ).set_index(
        tups.to_records(index=False)
    )

Output: (I replaced 0s with empty strings and dropped rows with only 0s)
print(res[(res == 1).any(axis = 1)].replace(0, '').to_markdown()) :
|        | 0   | 1   | 2   | 3   | 4   | 5   |
|--------|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|
|  ...   |     |     |     |     |     |     |
| (1, 2) |     | 1   | 1   | 1   | 1   | 1   |
|  ...   |     |     |     |     |     |     |
| (1, 5) |     |     | 1   |     | 1   |     |
|  ...   |     |     |     |     |     |     |
| (1, 7) |     |     | 1   |     |     |     |
|  ...   |     |     |     |     |     |     |
| (2, 5) |     |     | 1   |     | 1   |     |
|  ...   |     |     |     |     |     |     |
| (2, 7) |     |     | 1   |     |     |     |
|  ...   |     |     |     |     |     |     |
| (3, 4) |     | 1   | 1   |     | 1   | 1   |
| (3, 5) |     |     |     | 1   |     |     |
| (3, 6) |     |     |     | 1   | 1   |     |
| (3, 7) |     |     |     |     |     | 1   |
|  ...   |     |     |     |     |     |     |
| (4, 6) |     |     |     |     | 1   |     |
| (4, 7) |     |     |     |     |     | 1   |
|  ...   |     |     |     |     |     |     |
| (5, 6) |     |     |     | 1   |     |     |
| (5, 7) |     |     | 1   |     |     | 1   |
|  ...   |     |     |     |     |     |     |


This works but considering a df with a larger number of rows (e.g., 400-500) it is not so fast. Can you suggest how I can improve its performance? A suggestion could be that we can also remove duplicate binary rows from the resulting df

You could try using polars instead. Whree does the data from df come from. Could you directly create the res DataFrame? That would certainly help.

I also can recommend polars as it is really fast and I would prefer it instead of pandas. For really large data sets use spark :)
